# How to retrieve the month from a date column values in scala dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Given:

```
val df = Seq((1L, "04-04-2015")).toDF("id", "date")
val df2 = df.withColumn("month", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"date", "dd/MM/yy"), "MMMMM"))
df2.show()
```

I got this output:

```
+---+----------+-----+
| id|      date|month|
+---+----------+-----+
|  1|04-04-2015| null|
+---+----------+-----+
```

However, I want the output to be as below:

```
+---+----------+-----+
| id|      date|month|
+---+----------+-----+
|  1|04-04-2015|April|
+---+----------+-----+
```

How can I do that in sparkSQL using Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("month", date_format(to_date($"date", "dd-MM-yyyy"), "MMMM"))

df2.show
+---+----------+-----+
| id|      date|month|
+---+----------+-----+
|  1|04-04-2015|April|
+---+----------+-----+
```

NOTE:

- The first string (to_date) must match the format of your existing date

  - Be careful with: "dd-MM-yyyy" vs "MM-dd-yyyy"
- The second string (date_format) is the format of the output

Docs:

- [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_date-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-)
- [date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#date_format-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-)

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly related to this question but who wants to get a month as integer there is a `month` function:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("month", month($"date", "dd-MM-yyyy"))

df2.show
+---+----------+-----+
| id|      date|month|
+---+----------+-----+
|  1|04-04-2015|    4|
+---+----------+-----+
```

The same way you can use the `year` function to get only year.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing Wrong in your code just keeps your date format as your date column.
>   Here i am attaching screenshot with your code and change codes.

[image]

**HAppy Hadoooooooooooopppppppppppppppppppppp**

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @maheshgupta you wish! I was there first!! :p